# phoenix Join tables not using index hint

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

When using phoenix secondary index, and query non-primary, non-index, non-covered field, hint not working when join tables.

Here's the index

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON table_1 (f1, f2);
```

And this works with index:

```
select /*+ INDEX(table_1 my_index) */ f1, f2, f3 from table_1;
```

This not working with index:

```
select /*+ INDEX(table_1 my_index) */ a.f1, a.f2, a.f3, b.f4 from table_1 a
join table_2 b on a.f1=b.f1
where a.f1=? and a.f2=?
limit 10;
```

So adding `f3` to `covered field` is the only solution?

Comment: What is your explain plan for the second request ? My guess is the join makes it too complicated to compute a range scan from your index.